# Duplicate identifier 'express'.ts(2300)

Tags: typescript, express

I'm getting this error from express and I don't know why!
Does it have any to do with global variables?

Duplicate identifier 'express'.ts(2300)

[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIKVZ.png)

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import express from 'express'

export namespace JWTMiddleware {
    export const _sign = (userId: string): string => {
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET!)
        return token
    }

    export const _verify = (token: string): string => {
        const verification = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET!) as string

        console.log(verification)

        return verification
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you importing `express`? You don't use it in this module.

Comment: @spender I want to use it but it's giving me an error. I want to include (req,res) as parameters and use the exported functions as middlewares in the route

Comment: your 1st error is actually a warning that u have not used it after importing, 2nd error is because u have declared something with the same name 'express' after importing it.

Comment: if u are new to express, i recommend using a express starter code or a generator like this one: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html